# curl upload file in foreach change my post value

Tags: php, api, curl, file-upload

I have derectory and start scan dir get only jpg files and put in array after start foreach

```
foreach(files as file) {
    $cfile = new CURLFile('HERE FULL PATH TO FILE', $mime, $file);
    $target_url = "https://xxxxx.com/api/handler.php";
    $data = array('file' => $cfile, 'dir' => 'Derectory where need upload file if not exist i create in handler.php for example /var/www/xxx/test/');
    $ch = curl_init($target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // On dev server only!
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result) {
        curl_close($ch);
        // do something
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
        // error
    }
}
```

when I upload 1700 or more images 
curl start change my

> $_POST['dir']

for example in 1210-rd image that change my

> $_POST['dir']

from

> "/var/www/xxx/test/"

to

> "/var/www/xxx/te/va/www/x"

like this 
who know what the problem in this case Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't the `handler.php` or your `$files` source be more relevant then? You know, we appreciate reducing sample code to the necessary parts. But this curl_ excerpt seems not like the obvious cause to your issue.

Comment: in `handler.php` I put `$_POST['dir']` in .txt file and see how curl change my `$_POST['dir']` before send I'm dump `$data` and all is good i don't know why curl change my `$_POST['dir']`

Comment: Nobody can tell what happens to your `dir=` parameter, because that's the part which the excerpt leaves unexplained.